# Spring dynamic properties name

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm wondering if I can use dynamic properties name (for instance, using environment variables).

I want to use **@ConfigurationProperties** for injecting keys and values to HashMap. I tried it this way, but it didn't work.

application.yaml:

```
my-properties:
     ${my-env-variable-1}: env-1-value
     ${my-env-variable-2}: env-2-value
```

Comment: you can use Spring Profiles, but if your application is managed by a container such as Docker then you can specify and override environment variable values from it, and not deal with it in your actual code.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work for keys, but it works for values. I can use dynamic value of key. I'm interested if I can use dynamic keys of values.

Comment: but that is the opposite way of doing this. have the same key in every env, and have an external manager set a value in each env. your code should not be aware of the env it is running in. env variables are the "hooks" you need to plug in to.